# counting the number of occurences of string in a linked list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, counter

Hi I'm a beginner in C Programming. 
I wrote a code that takes contents from an input file to create a linked list.
So all the names are linked together.
Tom is linked with Jack and so on.
input file:

```
tom
jack
tom
mark
tom
jake
```

I wrote a function that counts the number of occurrence however no matter what I try I keep on getting warnings and count of `tom` is always `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN 50     

typedef struct node {
    char name[MAXN];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int count( node* head, char search_for) 
{ 
    node* current = head; 
    int count = 0; 
    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        if (current->name== search_for) 
           count++; 
        current = current->next; 
    } 
    return count; 
} 



int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    char buf[MAXN];

    node *first = NULL, *last = NULL;  


    while (fgets (buf, MAXN, file)) {


        node *head = malloc (sizeof(node));
        if (head == NULL) {         
            perror ("malloc-node"); 
            return 1;   
        }


        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;    


        strcpy (head->name, buf);
        head->next = NULL;


        if (!last)
            first = last = head;
        else {
            last->next = head;
            last = head;
        }
    }

    if (file != stdin) 
        fclose(file);
        node *ptr = first;
        printf("count of tom is %d", count(ptr->name, 't'));


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you compile that code as written, you're going to get a warning.  `if (current->name== search_for) ` is comparing a character pointer:  `current->name` to a character: `search_for`.  Fix that without using a cast and it will have a far better chance of working.  Note that in C you cannot use `==` to compare two strings.  `strcmp()` is a function designed to do this.

Comment: so instead of `if (current->name== search_for)` I should use `if(current->name==strcmp(search_for,"tom")` ?

Comment: No.  `strcmp()` takes two pointers to characters and returns an int.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html  So you'd pass `current->name` and `"tom"` as parameters, and consider them equal if and only if the return value is zero.  You need to consider changing the second parameter of `count()` from a `char` to a `char *`, that will let you pass in an arbitrary string to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code.

1. You're count function takes in a node and a character. It should take in a node and a character array (char *).
2. When you call count you are calling it with a char array and a char. You should be calling it with a node pointer and char array. Remember to designate strings with "" (i.e. "tom" not 'tom').
3. You cannot compare to char arrays with ==. To do this use [strcmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html).

Here is a working version of your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>

#define MAXN 50     

typedef struct node {
    char name[MAXN];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int count( node* head, char * search_for)  //Char * search_for instead of char search_for
{ 
    node* current = head; 
    int count = 0; 
    while (current != NULL) 
    { 
        if (strcmp(current->name,search_for) == 0) { //using strcmp instead of ==
           count++; 
        }
        current = current->next; 
    } 
    return count; 
} 



int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
    if (file == NULL)
        return 1;

    char buf[MAXN];

    node *first = NULL, *last = NULL;  


    while (fgets (buf, MAXN, file)) {


        node *head = malloc (sizeof(node));
        if (head == NULL) {         
            perror ("malloc-node"); 
            return 1;   
        }


        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;    


        strcpy (head->name, buf);
        head->next = NULL;


        if (!last)
            first = last = head;
        else {
            last->next = head;
            last = head;
        }
    }

    if (file != stdin) fclose(file);
    node *ptr = first;
    printf("count of tom is %d", count(ptr, "tom")); // ptr instead of ptr->name and "tom" instead of 'tom'
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cannot compare two arrays of characters with ==. Instead, you must use the strcmp() function. The first (or second, order doesn't matter) must be the name of the current node in the linked list, and the other one will be the parameter you are passing into the function (search_for). strcmp() will return 0 if they are the same, in which case you would then increment your count variable.